# AsyncRestTemplate + Coroutines

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I know AsyncRestTemplate is deprecated but anyway. Am I doing right writing code like this to marry AsyncRestTemplate with coroutines?

```kotlin
   suspend fun dodo(url: URL): String {
      val result = AsyncRestTemplate().getForEntity(url, String::class.java)
      return result.awaitBody()
   }

   suspend fun <T> ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<T>>.awaitBody(): T {
      while (this.isDone.not)
         yield()
      return this.get().body!!
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct but inefficient, since it is effectively a busy-wait loop repeatedly calling `ListenableFuture.isDone` until it finishes.

You should make use of the callback API provided whenever you need to convert between an async API and suspend functions:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> ListenableFuture<T>.await(): T = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    // Special handling for Future<*> objects
    cont.cancelFutureOnCancellation(this)

    addCallback(object : ListenableFutureCallback<T> {
        override fun onFailure(ex: Throwable) {
            cont.resumeWithException(ex)
        }

        override fun onSuccess(result: T) {
            cont.resume(result)
        }
    })
}
```

This will not waste time checking if the future finishes, but just tell the future to resume the suspended function when a result is actually available.

Comment: Thanks. But is `AsyncRestTemplate` non-blocking or it is just async?

Comment: It uses a `ListenableFuture` which supports both callbacks and blocking use. For coroutine support we simply adapt the callback interface.

Comment: All I wonder that is this `async support` blocks thread when performing IO operation?

Comment: It does not, the contract implies all blocking work is handled internally by `AsyncRestTemplate` since it returns a future and will not block your own thread unless you invoke a blocking operation yourself. Calling `Future.isDone` in a loop is actually worse than a blocking call since it keeps the thread active.

Comment: So it turns to that `AsyncRestTemplate` blocks thread when performing IO and it's not alternative to `WebClient` which is fully non-blocking.